# How to add activity indicator to UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UITextView` that gets and loads a file from a server. How do I add an activity indicator to show that it's loading? The server hosting it is a bit slow.

Here is code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.aliectronics.com.au/thefournobletruths.rtf")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

do {
    let options = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType]
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
    print(attributedString)
    textview2.attributedText = attributedString
    textview2.editable = false
} catch {
    NSLog("\(error)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use Data contents Of URL initializer to download data synchronously. There is no guarantee it will succeed. You need to download your data asynchronously using NSURLSession method dataTaskWithURL as I have already suggested to you at your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938652/2303865). Regarding your new question it has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28893660/2303865). Combining both answers you should be able to accomplish what you are trying to. More info commented at the code bellow::

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textview2: UITextView!
    // declare your activityIndicator
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    // you will need a new view for your activity indicator and a label for your message
    let messageFrame = UIView()
    let strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 160, height: 50))
    func displayActivityIndicator() {
        strLabel.text = "Loading file"
        strLabel.textColor = .white
        messageFrame.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        messageFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        messageFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        messageFrame.addSubview(strLabel)
        view.addSubview(messageFrame)
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // set your message frame (you can also position it using textview2.frame
        messageFrame.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 80, y: view.frame.midY - 25 , width: 160, height: 50)
        // call your activity indicator method
        displayActivityIndicator()
        // call your method to download your data asynchronously
        getRTFData(from: "http://thewalter.net/stef/software/rtfx/sample.rtf", textview2)
    }
    func getRTFData(from link: String,_ textView: UITextView) {
        // make sure your link is valid NSURL using guard
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        // creata a data task for your url
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in
            // use guard to make sure you get a valid response from the server and your data it is not nil and you got no errors otherwise return
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data, error == nil
            else { return }
            // you need to use dispatch async to update the UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // stop animating the activity indicator and remove the messageFrame from the view
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()

                // NSAttributedString data initialiser throws an error so you need to implement Do Try Catch error handling
                do {
                    textView.attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
                    textView.isEditable = false
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i have multiple urls with out duplicating code for every link and textview Thanks

Comment: check my edit you just need to add another parameter to the textView object and just pass it when you call that method

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the code how to display a simple activator indicator in SWIFT-

```
  var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)//choose from the indicator styles available by default
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)//set the frame of the indicator over here.
    activityIndicator.center = view.center//where you want to place. usually we place it at the centre of our superview
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)//adding the indicator
    activityIndicator.bringSubviewToFront(view)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
```

**Now wherever you want,we add as -**

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()//Here we start the animation
```

we usually start animation just before we load or make a call to load the data from URL.

**To remove & stop animating -**

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
```

Hope this would work for you,you can go over for more customizations if you like. There are many blogs and links that you can refer for more customizations.